# .NET MVC 6 Simple Authentication without database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've created a simple website in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6.

I have 1 controller with 1 index-method and view.

I need authentication on this with `[Authorize]`

I have a login-form on a view with an input taking a number. Users can log in if they can answer the right number to a calculation.. I need to check the answer in C#-code.

So basically i want a AuthenticationController with a Login(int answer) where i can check the result and redirect to the index-page. If they try to acces the index-page not logged in, they must be redirected to the login page :)

Possible in a simple way?

Comment: Read this [Using Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Any way to mark an comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this [Using Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html)